# Fan always running when on AC Fedora 25

Tags: laptop, fedora, fan, cooling, dell-inspiron

I have a dell inpiron 7520 15r se running Fedora 25. Whenever I plug in AC the fan goes on full speed. It turns off again when I unplug. I have tried laptop-mode-tools too.

```
$> cat /proc/i8k 
1.0 A11 -1 47 -22 3 -22 4500 -1 -22
```

Fan is running at 4500 rpm at only 47 degrees.

```
$> cat /proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode                             
2

$> cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors 
performance powersave

$> cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
powersave
```

The noise is driving me mad. The laptop does not overheat when unplugged even though the fan runs slower:

```
$> cat /proc/i8k                                                        
1.0 A11 -1 49 -22 3 -22 2800 -1 -22
```

Is there a way to even run it in battery mode even though it is plugged in?

Or maybe adjust the threshold for temperature?

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and experimentation, I've found two resources which were useful. The first is [Dellfan](https://github.com/clopez/dellfan), it's the only application that actually managed to control the fan, albeit only by setting the speed to zero, silent and takeoff speed (BIOS appears to be capable of finer adjustments).

I tried the i8kutils, but they did not really help much. They however provide a way to check the fan speed and temperature.

The second is [this forum question](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/fan-control-on-dell-latitude-e6520-4175580509/), which merges Dellfan with i8kutils and provides an example of a service which can manage the speed dynamically. I haven't tried that yet because I do not like the side effects of having BIOS control disabled.

I plan to write a custom service which will keep BIOS control enabled, but will periodically set the speed to the desired value. BIOS takes about half a second to realize that the speed is "too low" and changes the setting, so if I send the signal often enough, it should keep BIOS out of the picture, but it will regain control if the service is stopped or when it crashes.